# iOS: Loading second view controller without nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, xib

I have a project, which consists of the standard `AppDelegate` and `ViewController` files, but does not utilize `nib` files.

Here's the code:

**delegate header**

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *vc1;
@end
```

**delegate implementation**

```
// AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.vc1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.vc1;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**view controller header**

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view1 : UIViewController{
    UIButton *button;
}
@end
```

**view controller implementation**

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 30);
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    [button setTitle: @"Switch View" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview: button];

    [button addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

- (void) buttonClicked: (id)sender {
    SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
        //both methods throw the same error - no known class method for selector
    //[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];         
    [self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

When trying to load another `nib`-less `view controller` *(in the buttonClicked method above)*, it keeps throwing the error

> No known class method for selector 'presentViewController'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right method is the following:

```
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. This works since it's in a method - would it be possible to run this in a normal function instead?

Comment: what do you mean by normal function?

Comment: I just tried it and it works too. Thank you. I meant using a function instead of an Objective-C method: *(void) buttonClicked {...}*  and not   *(void) buttonClicked: (id)sender {...}*